# Micro service Architecture based on RESTful API's in java

Tags: java, rest, design-patterns, microservices

Best Architecture for implementing a **WebService** that takes requests from one side, save and enhance that and then call another service with new parameters.
is there any special `Design Pattern` for this?

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for an [event driven architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_architecture)

Comment: Do all services belong to your application or the last request will be made to an outside service? You can check api gateway pattern to enhance your request. After first request arrived to api gateway service. Api gateway can make additional requests and enhance the original request and pass it.

Comment: yes @barbakini, exactly last request will be made to an outside service.

Comment: To me it sounds like you want to have some sort of [gateway api](http://microservices.io/patterns/apigateway.html). But I don't recommend that personally. This intermediate service is not going to be easy to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a lot to go on, but from what you've said it sounds like a job for ["pipes and filters"](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/PipesAndFilters.html)!

To get a more precise answer, you might want to ask yourself some more detailed questions:

If you need to do any validation or transformation of the incoming message?  Will you want to handle all requests the same way, or are there different types?  Are the external services likely to change, and if so, will they do this frequently?  What do you want to do if the final web service call fails (should you rollback the database record?)? How do you want to report failures/responses - do you need to report these back?  Do you need a mechanism to track the progress of a particular request?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for a design pattern, I think you might want to compare the pros and cons of using microservices orchestration vs choreography in the context of your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need an immediate response to the calling system I would suggest to you to use [event-driven](http://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/event-driven-architecture/) approach if that's feasible. So instead of REST services, you will have a message broker and your services will be subscribed for certain events. This will hide your consumers behind the message broker which will make your system less coupled.

This can be implemented via **Spring Cloud Stream**, where you will have a Sink (microservice producing events, transformer - microservice that makes intermediate transformations possible and a source - microservice that receives a final result for further processing).

Another possible case could be **Camel**. It has basically all the integration patterns built in, so it should not be a problem to implement the solution either based on REST APIs or events.